# In Windows, Does SetCurrentConsoleFontEx change console's font size?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, font-size

Other guys recommend the [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686200.aspx) but I don't know how to apply it to my project.

**I want to change the font size of only some texts, not all texts.**

Does `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()` change the console's font size?

Or are there other ways to change it?

If there is, please show me the console function and a simple example.

Comment: While some attributes, like colors and blinking/bold/etc are per character, other things like font and size is not. If you change the font it's for the whole console window.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using SetCurrentConsoleFontEx to change the console's font size.  This affects the entire console window -- so like Joachim Pileborg already said, if you want mixed font sizes in a single console window, this won't help you.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
#include <Windows.h>

// PrintChars sends ASCII characters to console output
// for demonstration purposes.
// depends only on Win32 API
static void PrintChars() {
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD num_written;
    static const char* cr_lf = "\r\n";
    for(char c=' '; c<'\x7f'; ++c) {
        WriteFile(hStdout, &c, 1, &num_written, NULL);
        if(c % 16 == 15) WriteFile(hStdout, cr_lf, 2, &num_written, NULL);
    }
    WriteFile(hStdout, cr_lf, 2, &num_written, NULL);
}

// WaitEnter blocks execution until the user
// presses the enter key.
// depends only on Win32 API
static void WaitEnter() {
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    char buffer;
    DWORD num_read;
    do {
        num_read = 0;
        ReadFile(hStdin, &buffer, 1, &num_read, NULL);
    } while(num_read && buffer != '\n');
}

int main() {
    // Display some example characters
    PrintChars();

    // Wait for the user to see how the current font looks
    WaitEnter();   

    // Get a handle to the current console screen buffer
    HANDLE hcsb = CreateFileA("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi = {sizeof(cfi)};

    // Populate cfi with the screen buffer's current font info
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hcsb, FALSE, &cfi);

    // Modify the font size in cfi
    cfi.dwFontSize.X *= 2;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y *= 2;

    // Use cfi to set the screen buffer's new font
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hcsb, FALSE, &cfi);

    // Wait for the user to see the difference before exiting
    WaitEnter();
    CloseHandle(hcsb);
}
```