# SetCurrentConsoleFontEx for Making Text Bold

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, fonts

I'm trying to make a function (in C++) that uses the WinAPI to make something that resembles a "header" in the console. By "header," I simply want the text to be another color and bold. I'm able to change the color, but bolding the text is proving frustrating.

I've read mixed answers about making text bold using the `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`; some people say it's possible while others have said it's not (in a not very straightforward way). I came across a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36590430/11073848) that said bolding *and* color change can be applied to an individual character.

Here's what I'm trying. This code is simplified, of course.

```cpp
auto errormsg = []() { std::cout << "\nError!\n" << std::endl; };

HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font_info = { sizeof(font_info) };

try
{
    if (!GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(h, false, &font_info)) throw;
    auto old_font = font_info;

    font_info.FontWeight = FW_BOLD;
    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(h, false, &font_info)) throw;

    if (!SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, /* A short for color ID */)) throw;

    std::cout << /* Header text here */ << std::endl;

    // Restore old font and old font color...
}
catch (...)
{
    errormsg();
    exit(1);
}
```

Although I'm using C++ functionality here, I'm okay with a pure C solution; I prefer whatever is simplest, of course.

**Edit**
To clarify, the problem is when I restore the old font stuff, the entire console window is reverted back. I obviously don't want this to happen.

Comment: If you want a bold heading you could set the colour to full white instead of the dimmer version which is the usual default. With console output, it's not worth spendig too much time on. It's just a console, not for serious presentations.

Comment: A console screen buffer can only ever be assigned a single font. You cannot write a header in one font, and then use a different font for other text.

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem with that is the user has the ability to print the header in whatever color they want.

Comment: @IInspectable Is there a way to get around that? Perhaps using multiple screen buffers or some sort of multi-threading?

Comment: The question you linked does not say that an individual character can be bolded. *"This affects the entire console window ... if you want mixed font sizes in a single console window, this won't help you."*

Comment: @WeatherVane I was referring to the comment on the question, not the answer. 
*"While some attributes, like colors and blinking/bold/etc are per character, other things like font and size is not. If you change the font it's for the whole console window."* – Some programmer dude

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958156/how-to-set-c-c-console-text-in-bold-and-italic-in-windows) also says it can't be done using standard functions.

Comment: ... although one of its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131292/4142924) says you can. But the console needs to have terminal emulation, and my Windows console does not.

Comment: [This MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str) mentions "foreground intensity" etc.

Comment: That answer is wrong. It was written by someone that's not a fan of reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting). *"Bold"* here really means *"Applies brightness/intensity flag to foreground color"*.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the console.

If you want to support bold fonts by different in the console window, you may need to submit the feedback via feedback hub.

- [How to submit in the Feedback Hub app?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app)

Answer (score -1):

I guess all of what you need is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/window-and-screen-buffer-size